# How to install a package from an older version of TeXLive?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I am using TeXLive 2010. I wanted to try xelatex for better unicode support. But I am unable to install these new packages as the TeXLive mirrors have moved on to 2011.

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2010
 repository: 2011
(Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?)  Goodbye.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Updating to TeX Live 2011 would be the way to go, but I assume you don't want that for some reason. Note that TeX Live 2010 will not be updated any longer (but this doesn't mean that the latest versions of its packages is not newer than the one you have installed). TeX Live uses a Subversion version control repository, so you could get the older packages there. However, not necessary in the form you require :-( There are also TeX Live DVDs around, but they will not hold any newer packages than you already have.

Comment: IIUC, the question is not about more up-to-date packages, but about installing packages that were omitted in the initial installation. So the DVD would indeed be a solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

An archived version of TeX Live 2010's tlnet in its final state is kept on the TUG server. You can use it by doing

```
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final
```

then

```
tlmgr install collection-xetex
```

(for example) should work.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for exactly this. I didn't want to upgrade to 2011 at this point. I only wanted the latest package version distributed with final TeXLive 2010.

Comment: Hmm, I get *Unable to determine repository version*: You have TeX Live 2016 installed, but the version at ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/tlnet-final cannot be determined. (Using TeX Live Utility Version 1.28 (1.28) on macOS Sierra). It shows a modal dialog with that error, and then switches back to the (original) URL (which contains the wrong (2017) repository). Thus, I can't install any updates or add new packages.

Comment: UPDATE: I most likely got the above (and related) errors because I was going through a VPN marked as dodgy, and the TUG ftp server just refused connections (which didn't show up in the GUI, while trying to run it on the CLI as in the answer highlighted that particular problem).

Answer (score 4):

FYI, there are several mirrors of the historic repository (more are welcome), including some accessible via http(s), thus avoiding problems with ftp.

https://tug.org/historic/