# Version-switching for TeX Live

Tags: texlive, installing, mactex, tlmgr

The newly released MacTeX-2020 requires at least High Sierra, probably for good reasons. Unfortunately I am still on MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) because of other heritage software.

I am happy to install TL2020 directly instead, but I really like MacTeX's version-switching mechanism and use it often.

I understand from [TeX Live distribution not showing up in system preferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192455/tex-live-distribution-not-showing-up-in-system-preferences) that I'd only need the symbolic links inside `/Library/TeX/Distributions` to get it working. So -- is there an easy way to get or build the missing `TeXLive-2020.texdist`-file?

Comment: There is a version of TeX Live 2020 that you can install directly (you may have to wait a few days for the repositories near you to get it). Go to [http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html] and click on the `Unix Download` link for directions and please follow them so it allworks just like MacTeX install.

Comment: The http://www.tug.org/mactex/TeXDist-2020.pkg referred on the page you link me to, is exactly what I was looking for! (I never found it as I directly followed the Unix-install link from the TL homepage) I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a version of TeX Live 2020 that you can install directly (you may have to wait a few days for the repositories near you to get it). Go to [tug.org/mactex/index.html](https://tug.org/mactex/index.html) and click on the Unix Download link for directions and please follow them so it allworks just like MacTeX install

Comment: still true for TL 2021

Comment: and even for TL 2023

Comment: Yes, it takes several days (up to a week) for the distribution to get to all the CTAN repositories. Please be patient!!!

Comment: Nono, it's there and it's working fine. I just commented to document for anybody looking that your old answer still is valid with the newest TL