# Using mathdesign for TeX Live 2012 with TeX Live 2013 and the latest MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, texlive, mathdesign

For some reason, I need the old version of `mathdesign` (the one shipped with TeX Live 2012) to work smoothly with TeX Live 2013. Ideally, I'd like to be able to switch from one version to the other. Note that I still have TeX Live 2012 installed. How can I do that? (I run a Debian box.)

For the same reason, a colleague needs the old version to work with the latest version of MiMTeX. How can he do that?

Comment: Why don't you just adjust your `$PATH` (assuming you are on Un*x) and add the TeXlive 2012 installation? Then you can build the whole document using TL2012.

Comment: @HenriMenke I need `luatex` shipped with TL2013 and `mathdesign` shipped with TL2012 to work together.

Comment: Do you want to have bot versions of `mathdesign` or just the old one (TL2012) ?

Comment: @PaulPichaureau Well, ideally, I'd like to be able to switch from one version to the other. But above all, I need access to the tl2012 version of mathdesign.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an older `mathdesign` version from ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2012/tlnet-final/archive/ *(I got this from [How to install a package from an older version of TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-to-install-a-package-from-an-older-version-of-texlive))*. Download both files and then follow for both, TeX Live *and* MiKTeX, these instructions: [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

For temporary inclusion of the old font version I cannot say anything for Linux/MacOSX<sup>*)</sup>, but for Windows I do ***not*** recommend the first two points explained in [MiKTeX – Integrating Local Additions](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html):

- `latex` option `--include-path` will work for most packages, when everything is put into one folder – the now included one -, but does not work for fonts in a test here. And also this seems to be a MiKTeX specific command line option.
- Setting `TEXINPUTS` as system variable: In general in Windows this should be avoided. A simple `set texinputs=c:\localtexmf\` will remove the default search path of the TeX distribution – and also important: subfolders are not searched. I was not able to include them with the colported `set texinputs=c:/localtexmf//` (note, that I used slashes here) in both distributions, so the usual adding of more folders with semicolons does not matter anymore.

So for MiKTeX in Windows the opportunity of adding local root directories is first choice. The root for the older `mathdesign` version could then in MikTeX’ settings acticated or deactivated, and this would include an update of format files and filename data bank (FNDB).

Another idea would be to use an additional portable installation, if disk space does not matter. This would be possible for both TeX distributions. In both cases no renewal of FNDB and format files is necessary for every switch between both font versions, but you have to make sure, that all other needed packages are kept on the same level.

<sup>*)</sup>*For Linux/MacOSX you can probably find an answer here: [TeX Live - Definition of the TEXINPUTS variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/9237).*

Comment: (+1) While I'm still interested in the answer of this question, I can't test it right now. I'll let you know. Thanks.