# Latex with Hebrew

Tags: babel, polyglossia, hebrew

### The babel attempt

The following code, that contains Hebrew, is successfully imported to pdf using pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
%\sethebrew

\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{2015}
\maketitle

\sethebrew
שלום! זהו מסמך \LaTeX\  בעברית.
\end{document}
```

The problem is when writing Hebrew characters in the `\title` directive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\title{כותרת}
\author{Me}
\date{2015}
\maketitle

\sethebrew
שלום! זהו מסמך \LaTeX\  בעברית.
\end{document}
```

In such case, the following log file is created:  http://pastebin.com/FqQX2qKG
Notice the message:
`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file jerus10): Font jerus10 at 720 not found`

### The Polyglossia attempt

I've also tried using Polyglossia, as recommended by "egreg" [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139006/73508).
I copied his code and ran `xetex` on the file, but it provided the following error/log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=xelatex 2015.3.4)  4 MAR 2015 15:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./hebrew_polyglossia.tex
(./hebrew_polyglossia.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 10 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
Package: expl3 2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty
Package: l3seq 2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty
Package: l3int 2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty
Package: l3quark 2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty
Package: l3prg 2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count94
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty
Package: l3clist 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty
Package: l3token 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty
Package: l3prop 2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty
Package: l3msg 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty
Package: l3file 2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count98
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count99
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty
Package: l3skip 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty
Package: l3keys 2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count100
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty
Package: l3fp 2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty
Package: l3box 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty
Package: l3coffins 2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty
Package: l3color 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty
Package: l3luatex 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count111
\g__cctab_stack_int=\count112
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty
Package: l3candidates 2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count113
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count115
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count116
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count117
)
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count118
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count119
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count120
\l_fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l_fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l_fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
Variant \tl_gset:cV already defined; not changing it on line 69

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
Package: fontspec-patches 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty
Package: fixltx2e 2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 420.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 33.

*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \liningnums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 132.
.................................................
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.


(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count121
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \fontspec with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 41.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmainfont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 46.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setsansfont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 51.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmonofont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 56.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathrm with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 65.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setboldmathrm with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 69.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathsf with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 73.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathtt with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 77.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontfamily with arg. spec. 'mO{}m' on line 96.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontface with arg. spec. 'mO{}m' on line 100.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \defaultfontfeatures with arg. spec. 'om' on line
. 108.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \addfontfeatures with arg. spec. 'm' on line 144.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 156.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newAATfeature with arg. spec. 'mmmm' on line 164.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newICUfeature with arg. spec. 'mmm' on line 172.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \aliasfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line
. 201.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \aliasfontfeatureoption with arg. spec. 'mmm' on
. line 203.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontscript with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 208.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontlanguage with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 235.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \DeclareFontsExtensions with arg. spec. 'm' on
. line 256.
.................................................
Variant \prop_gput:cnV already defined; not changing it on line 582
Variant \prop_gput:cnx already defined; not changing it on line 583
\l_fontspec_tmp_int=\count122
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2087.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2092.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2097.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2102.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2013/06/27 v1.33.4 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTe
X

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
\etb@tempcnta=\count123
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
\XKV@depth=\count124
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXintercharclass4
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hebrew.ldf
File: gloss-hebrew.ldf polyglossia: module for hebrew

(./bidi.sty
Package: bidi 2007/04/30 v0.2.2 Bidirectional typesetting in XeLaTeX
\n@everypar=\toks19
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hebrewcal.sty
Package: hebrewcal 2012/04/29 v2.5 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted fro
m hebcal.sty in Babel)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def
\c@tmpA=\count125
\c@tmpB=\count126
\c@tmpC=\count127
\c@tmpD=\count128
\c@tmpE=\count129
\c@tmpF=\count130
)
\hebrewday=\count131
\hebrewmonth=\count132
\hebrewyear=\count133
\@common=\count134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babel-hebrewalph.def
File: babel-hebrewalph.def 2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)


! LaTeX Error: Command \hebrewnumeral already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...false\@gim@apostfalse\@hebrew@numeral{#1}}}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...false\@gim@apostfalse\@hebrew@numeral{#1}}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13563 strings out of 495525
 279639 string characters out of 6184337
 317031 words of memory out of 5000000
 16678 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3680 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 80 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,0n,37p,10420b,95s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

I've installed countless of packages, fonts etc., to no avail.
What is the problem and how should I fix it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.

---

### Edit #1:

"Ulrike Fischer" has directed me to remove the file "bidi.sty" from the local directory and to run `xelatex` again.
Here are the results (log file): http://pastebin.com/z24w4jwt

Notice that it requires a `bidi.sty` file: `` ! LaTeX Error: File `bidi.sty' not found. ``

---

### Edit #2:

I tried to install TeX Live 2010's tlnet as directed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-to-install-a-package-from-an-older-version-of-texlive/25092#25092).
But it has an incompatibility issue.

```
$ tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/dor/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
$ tlmgr init-usertree
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
$ tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
Continuing anyway ...
tlmgr: setting default package repository to ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final

### Here I installed the 'xzdec' package via Ubuntu Software Center

$ tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: setting default package repository to ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final
$ tlmgr install collection-xetex
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository are not compatible:
      local: 2013
 repository: 2010 (ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2010/tlnet-final)
(Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror? Just a guess.)
```

---

### Edit #3:

I installed TeX Live **2013**'s tlnet, as can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/KidD3NpW).
But when:

- running `xetex`, [it yields](http://pastebin.com/A1bYY0nz) `Undefined control sequence` error for `documentclass`.
- running `xelatex`, [it still yields](http://pastebin.com/ne2gnXU9) `` File `bidi.sty' not found `` error.

---

### Edit #4:

I [ran commands to install](http://pastebin.com/BCma7U3a) `bidi` and to update the packages. Results:

- `xetex`: error of `Undefined control sequence` for `documentclass`, [see details](http://pastebin.com/JUCjfgri)
- `xelatex`: error of `` File `iftex.sty' not found ``, [see details](http://pastebin.com/NJzu7Stg).
  So I installed it using the command `tlmgr install iftex`.
  Finally [an error of missing font](http://pastebin.com/zA3H2Cfx) arises: `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`, which is related to the `New Peninim MT` font. So I switched it to "Arial" and "arial" but still it failed for the same reason.
  So I searched in LibreOffice Writer which fonts I have that I can use for Hebrew, and found `DejaVu Sans` that worked!

Now it works!!! :) Thank you Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: In the xelatex example you are loading a bibi.sty from the current directory which looks very old. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did that and updated my original post with the results. Please review them..

Comment: Well you need to install bidi. You could try to update your texlive from an historic archive http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-to-install-a-package-from-an-older-version-of-texlive/25092#25092 (exchange 2010 with 2013), or you could install texlive 2014.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I installed `texlive` using Ubuntu Software Center but still the same results. Why would you recommend on downgrading to 2010? Is the 2014 version unstable?

Comment: You don't have 2014 but 2013. And I didn't suggest to downgrade to 2010 (which would be silly) but to install bidi with tlmgr (if you have the manager) from the 2013 historic repository. The link I sent shows how to do it for Texlive2010, but the method works in 2013 too, you only musst adapt the url of the repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've tried that but an incompatibility issue arises. See my 2nd edit.

Comment: Look I now said twice that you should adjust the method to 2013. You need to exchange everywhere "2010" with "2013". Call `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final` <---2013!! 2013!! 2013!!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh sorry, I didn't understand it that way. Explicitly writing "exchange X with Y" makes it clearer. Now I installed the 2013 version but the `bidi.sty` error consists.

Comment: did you really installed bidi or only setup the repository? try `tlmgr install bidi` or `tlmgr update --all`. And as a side remark: I wrote "exchange 2010 with 2013".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works!! thank you :) See my edit and please add your answer so I would accept it.

Answer (score 3):

To get Hebrew to work with `pdftex` you need to install [`culmus-latex`](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/) in order to have proper fonts. The `jerus10` file you see reference to was part of the now obsolete `Ivritex` package.

Typesetting Hebrew directly in LaTeX is a nightmare of directionality and I would recommend you to avoid it. [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) has good support for Hebrew and can be set up to work with either `pdftex` (using culmus-latex) or with XeTeX and `polyglossia` (following the instructions [here](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/)).

Comment: The instructions do not appear to say anything about setting it up in LyX?

Comment: Right, I linked to the wrong post, the correct one is: [Creating a Hebrew Document in LyX 2.1 with XeTeX](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-a-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/)

Comment: Indeed, using `polyglossia` and setting `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}` makes the document Right to Left with English words in the wrong direction. Why is it such a nightmare to make the RTL work properly in  LaTeX? I'd really like to write the Tex source code myself, without other "supporting" programs..

Comment: @Guy Thanks for the article, very helpful! Question:
I'm using the F12 shortcut but it only changes the direction of the text: RTL or LTR.
I need to also press ALT + SHIFT in order to actually change the language.
Any idea on how do I change the language with a single click?

Answer (score 0):

For unicode Hebrew, the easiest is to use xelatex and the "Lucida Grande" font.