# Downloaded: xlop.sty and xlop.tex file. Which specific directory to install ?

Tags: packages

I like to install package called :xlop from CTAN
I use Mac OS X 10.9 and TeXShop 3.48.

Which specific directory do I put these two files?

Do I put it at 
A. I have /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/textmf-local ?

B. or  /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist directory?

Comment: As you seem to be using BasicTeX I'd recommend using the package manager to install a managed version. You've got BasicTeX 2013 so you'll need to point your system to a place you can still get updates: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-to-install-a-package-from-an-older-version-of-texlive.

Comment: For Ubuntu, you can find it here: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xlop`

Answer (score 0):

1. All the `xlop.sty` and `xlop.tex` files are kept under this directory

   ```
   /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base
   ```
2. Do a `$sudo cp` your `.sty` and `.tex` files into the above directory
3. Do a `$ sudo texhash` at the above directory.. It should give a message  `Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-config.ls-R...` and later `Done`.

Comment: I don't use OSX (or whatever), but that has a 99.99% chance of being the wrong place to install any package.