# Tex live 2015 frozen forever

Tags: texlive, mactex

I am using MacTeX 2015 on OS X 10.10.5 and do not want to upgrade to 2016 just yet. However, I would like to upgrade to the latest packages versions.

After upgrading `tlmgr` I first got an error that the repository was outdated. I was able to fix that thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313823/67042), i.e.

```
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
```

However, now I get the following error when doing `tlmgr update -all`:

```
TeX Live 2015 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates for tlmgr present.
tlmgr: no updates available
```

Can anyone help me set up texlive so that the packages are updated?

Comment: that doesn't look like an error, just a statement that you are up to date with the final version of tl2015

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks & True. But I did not update in 6 months, so I would be surprised. Is there a way to check manually...?

Comment: well one of the later updates was to latex so the latex format should be 2016/03/31 (not for example 2015/01/01 or 2015/10/01 which were earlier releases in the tl2015 cycle)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean something like `tlmgr info latex`? There I get `cat-date:    2015-08-03 05:43:12 +0200`

Comment: no I just meant look at the top of the terminal or log output from any latex run and look for something like `LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2` (which is the current one in texlive 2016, but you should get 2016/03/31 if I recall correctly)

Comment: Once you have updated TeX Live 2015 to its final frozen version, there's no other update to do, at least automatically. You may update packages manually, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Did you install a full texlive or only a basic version (as suggested by the 2015basic)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer basic version

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>` Which is strange since I certainly upgraded in 2015

Comment: @egreg Oh - so there is no "final" / maximum version of the packages that I could update to?

Comment: there were some issues start of last year with some mac versions being stuck at unpatched 2015/01/0, never fully resolved, there were patch levels 1,2 of that and and a release 2015/10/01 in october with two further patch releases, and a release in march 2016.  But actually I don't understand why you would want to do this update at all. If you are in the middle of a big project, don't update, stick with what you have, and when it's safe to update, update to tl2016 or tl2017 or whatever is current. Why do the pain of doing an update, but prevent yourself getting the latest fixes?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are probably right -- thank you! I have some issues with a specific package and I wanted to try upgrading it first. But maybe it is best if I look for another workaround.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no real answer other than “because the distribution is not updated any more”.

Comment: @egreg Actually, after running into this again and having this question being ranked highest on Google, I would like to see your answer (i.e. “because the distribution is not updated any more") be the accepted one here to be honest...

Comment: @n1000 Maybe you can edit your question to make it more general, so it can receive an answer also for the next releases of TeX Live.