# Cannot update TeXLive 2016

Tags: texlive

When I try to update TeXLive with tlmgr, I get the following error:

```
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579.
```

I saw many people with the same error, but the answers were generally to switch to the 2015 repository. In my case, however, I did install the 2016 version, as described [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html). I read that running update-tlmgr-latest.sh, available [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html), could help, but it only outputs this:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live ManagerUpdater............................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

Basically, I have the [same question as Gomi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313768/tlmgr-unknown-directive), but I did perform a new installation of the 2016 version of TeXLive and I would like it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: In a terminal, did you try `kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT`?

Comment: It prints an empty line.

Comment: What does ’which tlmgr‘ say?

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I installed TexLive 2016 on Linux Mint according to the instructions on https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html , but `xelatex` is not installed, and when I try to update it using `tlmgr`, also according to the instructions on that website, I get this error message.