# Tlmgr error: Unknown Directive

Tags: installing, tlmgr

Note: this is all because I wanted to use tlmgr to install `subfiles.sty`.  It's likely there's an easier way of dealing with this problem, but I might as well try getting `tlmgr` to work.

I seem to be getting the same error as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313768/why-getting-this-error-tlmgr-unknown-directive), where the issue ended up being mismatched texlive and tlmgr versions.

**Issue:**
When I run `tlmgr update --all`, I get the following output:

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!) Unknown directive
>   ...containerchecksum
>   c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955...
>   , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line
>   210,  line 5579.

The installation log is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HtE2B7_Z9JU3VuRG9ON2dsclU/view?usp=sharing).  It appears that there aren't any errors, though there are quite a number of warnings.  The majority of the warnings seem to be of the form:

> warning:  is already defined (\relax it first)

My installation is from `install-tl` (I think this is upstream?).

I've tried downloading and running `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`, as I read this can be helpful.
This gives the output:

> Verifying archive integrity... All good. Uncompressing TeX Live
>   Manager
>   Updater............................................................................................................................................................................
>   ./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich
>   --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT. ./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.

This is confusing, as running `kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT`
 by itself outputs `/usr/local/texlive/2016`, so it appears the PATH is set.

It appears that `texlive` itself is working fine - I can compile documents, and running `latex small2e` seems to output reasonable files.  To reiterate, this is a new texlive 2016 install. I initially installed off of synaptic, but when I realized that's likely out of date I deleted it, and installed via `install-tl`.

**UPDATE** As (for unrelated reasons) I reinstalled my OS the day prior, I decided to reinstall my OS to fix this.

Comment: what does `which tlmgr` say, it looks like you are picking up an old one as it is using `/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg` ie your system tex not the one in `/usr/local/texlive/2016` and the error message you show is expected from an old tlmgr from 2015 or earlier that doesn't have the checksum support used by the texlive 2016 repositories.

Comment: `which tlmgr` says `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

Comment: hmm  sorry then I give up (probably someone with more recent debian experience will be around better than my guesses:-)

Comment: The version of `tlmgr` you are running is definitely NOT from upstream. When you ran the update command, did you use `sudo` or switch to root or what? I guess when you ran `which` and `kpsewhich`, you ran them as your ordinary user, correct?

Comment: I used `sudo` instead of switching to root, and ran `which` and `kpsewhich` as an ordinary user.  Should I remove the install I made as a user and redownload it as root?

Comment: When you deleted Debian's TL, did you make sure everything was gone? Did you then install a dummy package to satisfy `apt` or whatever?

Comment: I didn't make sure everything was gone, but I deleted it through `synaptic` and used the "completely delete" option.  I'm not totally sure entirely what that entails.

Comment: So when you ran `install-tl`, did you use `sudo`? You must have done something like that for it to be in `/usr/local`. You don't need to undo that `/usr/local` install. You just need to eliminate the old one and install a suitable dummy.

Comment: What does `sudo which tlmgr` give?

Comment: `sudo which tlmgr` gives `/usr/bin/tlmgr`

Comment: Indeed, you have a stale Debian TL installation which is competing with your new one. This will cause endless confusion if left to fester.

Comment: How would I remove the Debian TL distribution?

Comment: Read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=2|0.0000 before you try anything else. It explains what you need to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a reinstallation solves the problem.