# Set PATH to use the current TeX Live bin directory

Tags: texlive, installing

I run Ubuntu 16.04. I want to run **update-tlmgr-latest.sh** on my machine (cf. *The underlying problem* farther down for details about that), but before I do this, https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html says under "Disaster recovery" that I should

> be sure your PATH is set to use the current TeX Live bin directory; the recovery archives use `kpsewhich` from PATH to figure out where to unpack themselves.

**The problem, in short**: I am definitely not "sure" about anything related to any of this, since my ubuntu capabilities are strictly limited to a minimum.

I tried the following:

---

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive
```

produces

```
Package 'texlive' is not installed, so not removed
```

apt-get does not recognize my texlive installation, although it's installed, since I use it to compile my LaTeX documents.

---

```
which install-tl
```

has no output

---

```
which tlmgr
```

and

```
sudo su
which tlmgr
```

both produce

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr
```

so root and the user account recognize the same directory for tlmgr (I think this might be important, but I don't really know why)

---

### The underlying problem

I am trying to

```
tlmgr update --self
```

but all of

```
tlmgr update --all
tlmgr update --list
tlmgr update --self
```

gives me (this is taken from [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313768/why-getting-this-error-tlmgr-unknown-directive), but only the checksum and the last line number are different, the rest is the same):

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!) Unknown directive 
...containerchecksum
c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... ,
please fix it! at
/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, line 5579.
```

and

```
sudo su
tlmgr update --self
```

outputs

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /root/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
```

---

I guess I am running Debian TL, since it's switching to user mode.

---

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

results in a double installation, cluttering the system.

The steps described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/117274) are a bit overwhelming, but if you think this would be the absolute best thing to do, I will.

Comment: I read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344972/tlmgr-error-unknown-directive, which seems to have the same initial problem, but I don't understand what this person did to solve his or her problem (apart from a fresh install, which I would like to avoid at this point in time if possible).

Comment: In a terminal execute `echo $PATH`. If the path to your TeXLive binaries is included, that's done. I guess you haven't installed TeXLIve through the Ubuntu repositories but used the installer. That's why apt-get says that TeXLive isn't installed.

Comment: `tex-common` `texinfo` `texlive` and `texmf` are all in the directory `/usr/share/` if that's on any importance.

Comment: How did you initially install TeXLive on your system?

Comment: @Skillmon that is correct, I didn't use apt-get to install. I don't remember how I installed it, but I think I downloaded the installation file from tug.org/texlive

Comment: How should apt-get then know that it is installed on the system :)

Comment: `echo $PATH` gives `/home/thymaro/anaconda3/bin:/home/thymaro/bin:/home/thymaro/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: And the binaries of your TeXLive are where? In `/usr/share/`? You might set the `PATH` to include the folders of your binaries with `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/texlive/binaries` (obviously with `/path/to/texlive/binaries` replaced by the correct path to the containing folder). This way for the current terminal ONLY the `PATH` is set to include the desired folder.

Comment: To find your binaries you might execute something like `whereis pdftex` or similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61858/discussion-between-thymaro-and-skillmon).

Comment: I would suggest you just do the `apt-get install` routine and delete your own installation. That way, you can just let the system package manager handle all updates. That is, after all, the beauty of Debian and its derivatives - 99.9% of the time, packages just work.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer I would love to do that. However, I want to cleanly remove my current installation (TL 2016). I don't figure I can just go into the installation directory and delete the texlive directory, now, can I?

Comment: @thymaro I think it *should* work. What I would do in addition is to delete `tlmgr` from `/usr/bin`. Actually it could very well be that `/usr/bin/tlmgr` is just a symlink that points to some file in your texlive folder. I would try the folllowing: as root, `cd /usr/bin` and `ls -l | grep texlive` to list all executables that are symlinks to texlive. If you find any, delete them all.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but synaptic somehow managed to find my texlive installation and I removed everything tex-related ("mark for complete removal"). Ugh... the frustrating part is not knowing how something works when before it didn't. I don't remember doing anything different between before and after posting the question. The above-mentioned directories are gone, I can't find any symlinks with `grep`, nothing shows up when I `whereis pdftex` etc.. I guess it's gone. I'm off to install TL 2017.