# `titlepages.sty' not found

Tags: packages, titles

i'm trying to use the [titlepages](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages) package

```
\usepackage{titlepages}
```

but `TeX Maker` gives me this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `titlepages.sty' not found. Type X to quit or
>    to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

On Ubuntu 16.04, i install the following but the error still happens:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to install either `texlive-publishers` or `texlive-lang-english`. Please see this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system.

Comment: @koleygr i have `texlive`, `texlive-latex-base`, `texlive-latex-recommended` and `texlive-latex-extra` installed. same issue.

Comment: Ok... removing my comment and looking to find it (Did you checked @Masroor's suggestion?)

Comment: [this search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=titlepages.sty) shows that a copy of `titlepages.sty` is in the `texlive-latex-recommended-doc`. I manually copy and gunzip the sty file and copy it alongside my main tex file. this solves the error.

Comment: Where did you found the zipped file? If you downloaded you can just run `sudo apt install texlive-latex-recomended-doc` because `texlive-latex-recomended`  doesn't install this.

Comment: @koleygr this is what i did: `sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended-doc`, then `cp /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/memoir/titlepages.sty.gz`, then `gunzip ./titlepages.sty.gz`.

Comment: Ok. I just tried to load in my code and have the same issue. I suppose this is the way. I have never used it anyway.

Comment: `tlmgr install` in Masroor's link shows the missing `xzdec`, solved by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262011/142054). After that, when i try `tlmgr install texlive-publishers`, i'm seeing the `Unknown directive` error, discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344972/tlmgr-error-unknown-directive)

Comment: @JeffXiao You are making a simple situation complicated. Simply issue the command, `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Masroor i've tried both `sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers` and `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-english`; still seeing the `"titlepages.sty" not found` error. thanks for the reply by all means

Comment: There is no such file. There is no LaTeX package you can use that way. The TeX Live package of that name only has some examples you can copy.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right. it turns out the `titlepages.sty` is not meant to be used that way. i wonder why it is named as a style file. thanks for the comment

Comment: By the way, you might want to take a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280