# Where can I find the official TeX Live 2016 distribution for Unix?

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2016

Until now, I am installing TeX Live via the network and I'm using `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz` to get the installer.
However, since TeX Live 2017 was released, this URL will give me the installer for TeX Live 2017, which breaks for me for some edge cases. I need to install TeX Live 2016 explicitly, however I can't seem to find the correct URL for the installer.
What I found is `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, but when I try to install it with the same commands as for the usual installer I get

```
./install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2016
 repository: 2017
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
(For more, see the output of install-tl --help, especially the
 -repository option.  Online via http://tug.org/texlive/doc.)
```

Does anyone know how I can explicitly get the installer for TeX Live 2016?

Comment: you can get the 12MB large installer from here: http://www.chip.de/downloads/c1_downloads_hs_getfile_v1_80217685.html?t=1500392721&v=3600&s=d5ea89562f8041860ca64432f22af1aa , but the complete `.iso` is another story

Comment: @naphaneal The only really interesting thing are the mirrors.

Comment: You have the correct installer, but you need to tell it to use the historical FTP repo not the mirror network. That's covered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/how-to-install-a-package-from-an-older-version-of-texlive/25092#25092: not sure if this is therefore a dupe or not ...

Comment: @TeXnician I wonder if there's an archive of some sort, which provides previous versions.

Comment: @naphaneal That _is_ ftp://tug.org/historic: it's just a question of telling the installer to use it. (The historical archive is all unmodified from the release versions, so the default download location is the mirror network.)

Comment: Here you'll find the iso: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/texlive2016.iso

Comment: @JosephWright I think it's a dup since only the packages are missing (apparently the OP found the installer).